# Call getUsers() function from MongoDB driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-query

I am currently building an api application that checks the status and gets information of various types of dbs(i.e. Mongo, MySQL) using Sailsjs such as users, depending on a user input. Here is a snippet of the code I am working on.   The local host is just the test database I am connecting to, but in the future it will be supplied by the user.

```
      var mp = require('mongodb-promise');
      var MongoClient = require('mongodb');



  mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://@localhost:27017/test")
      .then(function(db){
          db.getUsers().then(function(users){
           res.ok(users);
         })
      })
   .fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

I am attempting to use promises for the async issue.  The problem I am having is that it doesn't work. It tells me that that Object[object object] has no method 'getUsers'.   I have searched and can't seem to find a solution that works.

If I change the function to the below, I get the some data back.

```
 mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://@localhost:27017/IMS")
     .then(function(db){
        db.stats().then(function(stats){
         return res.ok(stats);
        })
    })
   .fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    dbObject.vipUp = false;
    })
```

I am not sure what the issue is or how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here is using the node native driver methods to connect and inspect the database. There is in fact "no such method" as `.getUsers()` here in this API or in fact in any other API.

The `.getUsers()` function is just a "shell helper" that is basically implemented like this:

```
function (args) {
    var cmdObj = {usersInfo: 1};
    Object.extend(cmdObj, args);
    var res = this.runCommand(cmdObj);
    if (!res.ok) {
        var authSchemaIncompatibleCode = 69;
        if (res.code == authSchemaIncompatibleCode ||
                (res.code == null && res.errmsg == "no such cmd: usersInfo")) {
            // Working with 2.4 schema user data
            return this.system.users.find({}).toArray();
        }

        throw Error(res.errmsg);
    }

    return res.users;
}
```

So what you should be able to see here is that this normally wraps a "command" form, or otherwise falls back for compatibility with MongoDB 2.4 to querying the `system.users` collection on the current database.

Therefore, instead of calling a method that does not exist, you then need to use the [`.command()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#command) method instead:

```
mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://@localhost:27017/test")
      .then(function(db){
          db.command({ "usersInfo": 1}).then(function(users){
           res.ok(users);
         })
      })
   .fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Or in the case of connecting to a MongoDB 2.4 instance, then fetch from the [`.collection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#collection):

```
mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://@localhost:27017/test")
      .then(function(db){
          db.collection('system.users').find().toArray().then(function(users){
           res.ok(users);
         })
      })
   .fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

At any rate, you really should be establishing the database connection elsewhere in your application ( or re-using the underlying driver connection from another store ), and then calling methods on the connection already establihed. This is always preferable to creating a connection on the request of the information you want to retrieve.

Also, recent versions of the [node native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/) support promises right out of the box. So there may be no need to configure in anything else, depending on how you intend to use it.